# Symfony 4 : how to override Fosuserbundle validation?

Tags: fosuserbundle, symfony4

I use Symfony 4 and I try to override Fosuserbundle validation.xml by creating a new validation.xml file in config/validator/ but it does not work. It always uses default validation.xml, never the one I created.

I would like to change validation constraints for user registration.

config/packages/fos_user.yaml

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: App\Entity\User
    from_email:
        address: "test@domain.com"
        sender_name: "test@domain.com"
    registration:
        form:
            type: FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
            name: fos_user_registration_form
            validation_groups:  [RegistrationValidation]
```

config/packages/framework.yaml

```
framework:
    secret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%'
    csrf_protection: true
    validation: { enabled: true }
    ...
```

config/validator/validation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<constraint-mapping xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/constraint-mapping"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/constraint-mapping
    http://symfony.com/schema/dic/constraint-mapping/constraint-mapping-1.0.xsd">

<class name="FOS\UserBundle\Model\User">

    <property name="username">
        <constraint name="NotBlank">
            <option name="message">fos_user.username.blank</option>
            <option name="groups">
                <value>RegistrationValidation</value>
            </option>
        </constraint>
        <constraint name="Length">
            <option name="min">4</option>
            <option name="minMessage">fos_user.username.short</option>
            <option name="max">180</option>
            <option name="maxMessage">fos_user.username.long</option>
            <option name="groups">
                <value>RegistrationValidation</value>
            </option>
        </constraint>
    </property>
</class>
```

I created a new validation group named RegistrationValidation.

As you can see in the sample above, I try to set the min length of the username on 4 caracters, but it always take 2 as the min length, the value that is defined in the default Fosuserbundle validation.xml.

Does someone know how to do that ? Documentation is not very clear and not up to date about Fosuserbundle with Symfony 4.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution seems to be using

```
<class name="App\Entity\User">
```

instead of

```
<class name="FOS\UserBundle\Model\User">
```

in **config/validator/validation.xml**. Indeed, "**App\Entity\User**" is the User class defined in **config/packages/fos_user.yaml**.

Nevertheless, validation.xml does not seem to work for fields like email or plainPassword for which minLength (for example) is not applied.

```
<property name="plainPassword">
        <constraint name="NotBlank">
            <option name="message">fos_user.password.blank</option>
            <option name="groups">
                <value>RegistrationValidation</value>
            </option>
        </constraint>

        <constraint name="Length">
            <option name="min">6</option>
            <option name="minMessage">fos_user.password.short</option>
            <option name="groups">
                <value>RegistrationValidation</value>
            </option>
        </constraint>
</property>
```

It is even true with the default validation.xml of Fosuserbundle which defines constraints that are not taken into account when the registration form is rendered. I solved this problem by setting constraints directly in my twig form which override the fosuserbundle's one.

Hope this will help. If you have any other solution, don't hesitate to post it.